# Is plaid compatible with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, plaid

I want to integrate plaid workflow in my angular application, Is plaid compatible with angular or is there any reference material where I can go through plaid integration with angular

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Plaid Angular SDK and thus no official Plaid documentation on this topic -- however, if you Google, you should be able to find some community SDKs for using Angular with Plaid.

Comment: I'm utilizing typing from the plaid package in Angular. Pretty much the same. What are your thoughts on this?

https://twitter.com/dale_nguyen/status/1533473693225074688